# How can I update my private boolean property?

Tags: php, oop, object, private

my "fields" entity:

```
  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
  */
  private $color;




public function getColor(): ?bool
  {
    return $this->color;
  }

  public function setColor(?bool $color): self
  {
    $this->color = $color;

    return $this;
  }
```

I have difficulties to update my private property:

```
$field = "color"
$content = 1;
$value->{$field} = $content;
```

I get the error message:

> Cannot access private property App\Entity\Fields::$color

So I tested this:

```
$value->setColor(1);
```

But I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "setColor" of
>   class "stdClass".

Everything works well wenn I change private to public.
But I just cannot figure out how to set the value with a private property.

Comment: `$value` is not an instance of the class you posted partial code from.

Comment: Is there a way to check this before, if it is an instance?

Comment: `instanceof` construct.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use some specific ORM library…? What exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    private $attribute;

    public function getAttribute(){
        return $this->attribute;
    }

    public function setAttribute(?int $value){
        if($value)
        $this->attribute = $value;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass;

//$obj->attribute = 3; //this won't work because attribute is private

$obj->setAttribute(42);

echo $obj->getAttribute();
```

Works as expected and ouputs `42`; Try to create a new object of your class and do the same and see if it works.